How to create a structure where one object depends on another
I have some library which provides types Foo and Bar, where Bar contains a reference to Foo. I am trying to create a struct, Baz, which holds both Foo and Bar:
struct Foo {}

struct Bar<'a> {
    foo: &'a Foo,
}

struct Baz<'a> {
    foo: Foo,
    bar: Bar<'a>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }
}

impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    fn new(foo: &'a Foo) -> Self {
        Self {
            foo
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Baz<'a> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let foo = Foo::new();
        Self {
            foo,
            bar: Bar::new(&foo),
        }
    }
}

Rust playground
My attempt fails,
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `foo`
  --> src/lib.rs:29:9
   |
29 | /         Self {
30 | |             foo,
31 | |             bar: Bar::new(&foo),
   | |                           ---- `foo` is borrowed here
32 | |         }
   | |_________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

and
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `foo`
  --> src/lib.rs:31:27
   |
28 |         let foo = Foo::new();
   |             --- move occurs because `foo` has type `Foo`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
29 |         Self {
30 |             foo,
   |             --- value moved here
31 |             bar: Bar::new(&foo),
   |                           ^^^^ value borrowed here after move
   |
note: if `Foo` implemented `Clone`, you could clone the value

Implementing the compilers' suggestion resolves the second error, but I'm still left with the first. What is the best way to handle this with Rust?

This doesn't work because you cannot create a struct that contains a value and a reference to the value, directly or indirectly.
One solution for your problem is to use a Rc<Foo> to wrap the value.
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Foo {
}

impl Foo {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
        }
    }
}

struct Bar {
    foo: Rc<Foo>,
}

impl Bar {
    fn new(foo: Rc<Foo>) -> Self {
        Self {
            foo
        }
    }
}

struct Baz {
    foo: Rc<Foo>,
    bar: Bar,
}

impl Baz {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let foo = Rc::new(Foo::new());

        Self {
            foo: Rc::clone(&foo),
            bar: Bar::new(foo),
        }
    }
}

This way, both Bar and Baz share a reference to foo, with the ownership shared by the Rc and its clone.
See it in action in the playground.

Both Foo and Bar are library code, I cannot change their signatures.

@mfurseman You may need to show what Foo and Bar actually are, then. The answer given the exact structs in your question is "you cannot do this."

They are pipewire-rs' MainLoop and SignalSource. I think this distils the issue I'm having down into a general case though, which I imagine arrises when wrapping C APIs often.
